# Busca mongodb em PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Estou com dificuldades em retornar os registros por um filtro de data. Tenho o seguinte documento JSON:

```js
{
        "_id": "111090485635468_1098582396886267",
        "1098582396886267_1098592810218559": {
            "fb_id": "1098582396886267_1098592810218559",
            "created_time": {
                "date": "2016-07-28 20:32:06.000000",
                "timezone_type": 1,
                "timezone": "+00:00"
            },
            "from": {
                "picture": {
                    "height": 261,
                    "is_silhouette": false,
                    "url": "https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-xaf1\/v\/t1.0-1\/p148x148\/13179438_970835299696887_7000909019670413123_n.jpg?oh=b4f9ecf8f00f8cb22a02874ec0bc7d96&oe=5815B673&__gda__=1479588815_6a2efe74184209e4b419783f02250c5d",
                    "width": 148
                },
                "name": "Jhonathan Vinicius",
                "id": "1020748971372186"
            },
            "message": "Uma string qualquer...",
            "comment_count": 7,
            "like_count": 11,
            "last_update": "29\/07\/2016 22:36:13"
        }
```

Preciso filtrar todos os registros entre datas, tentei algo do tipo:

```
...
  $user = $c_users->find(   ['_id.fb_id.created_time.date' => [ '$gte'=> "2016-01-29 00:00", '$lt' => "2016-07-30 00:00" ] ]);  
....
```

E não me retorna nada. Fico grato quem puder colaborar!

Comment: Se aqui `[ '$gte' => ...` a intenção era passar um valor pela variável, mude para `[ '"{$gte}"' => ... `. O mesmo em `$lt`

Comment: Pode explicar o porque essa estrutura de documento? Ao meu ver `1098582396886267_1098592810218559` poderia ser um array de objetos... esse id seria um post?

Answer (score 1):

A sua referência ao campo está errada. Ao invés de `_id.fb_id.created_time.date`, use `1098582396886267_1098592810218559.created_time.date`.

```
$user = $c_users
    ->find([
        '1098582396886267_1098592810218559.created_time.date' => [
            '$gte'=> '2016-01-29 00:00',
            '$lt' => '2016-07-30 00:00',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Não sei se está correto... _id não é um objeto

Comment: @gmsantos bem notado, corrigi a resposta.

Comment: O problema é que essa query só vai funcionar nesse caso específico. Vejo que o problema é mais em baixo, na forma que está modelado o objeto.